# Why did chrome stop to open <a href hyperlinks embedded in bxslider divs

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, href, bxslider

Since some days chrome does not follow any product links in divs on my site. The links seem to be correct and are shown when the mouse pointer is moved over them, but on click there is no reaction of the Chrome browser. All not-working links are embedded in backslider divs. At Firefox / IE / Opera these links work fine. The problem only exists under Chrome in PC mode, left mouse clicks on links are ignored, right mouse click on link "open in new tab" works fine. When using in tablet / touch mode links work. Tried on different PCs, reinstalled chrome. Chrome version 73.0.3683.86

See behaviour on website : https://www.ep-mediastore-ab.de/index.php

...

```
<a href="https://www.ep-mediastore-ab.de/akku-für-braava-320-2000mah-nimh-p-11605.html">
  <div style="background:url(product_thumb.php?img=images/Artikelbilder/01/16/11605.gif&amp;m=72263&amp;w=99.9&amp;h=100) no-repeat 8px center; height:120px; width:140px;"></div>
  <div class="roundbox_text">Akku für Braava 320 2000mAH NiMH</div><div class="roundbox_small_prodprice">10.00 €</div>
</a>
```

...

a mouseclick on this link should open the product page, but nothing happens

Any help is highly appreciated

Klaus

Comment: Same thing happens to my site as well

Answer (score 5):

fixed it.

Problem was bxslider version.

changed:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="/includes/functions/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Hope it helps Albert.

Klaus